# How to extract images from video as part of encoding in Azure Media Services v3?

Tags: azure, encoding, azure-media-services

Here is what I am trying to do.

I am analyzing videos and based on my analysis I know at certain time intervals I need to capture a screenshot. I want this to be taken care of as part of encoding but I don't see any documentation that lets me achieve it in v3. Is this even possible in v3?

Answer (score 1):

This feature (key frames) is available on Video Indexer. More info in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/scenes-shots-keyframes

Comment: The link provided above returns a 404, but I believe this is the correct URL now: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-video-indexer/scenes-shots-keyframes

Comment: it was available in 2020

Answer (score 1):

You can use the v3 APIs to generate thumbnails at fixed intervals. In the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/customize-encoder-presets-how-to), you can see how the PngImage and PngFormat elements are used. You can also output JPEG images - the schema details are [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/mediaservices/resource-manager/Microsoft.Media/stable/2018-07-01/Encoding.json).